# email are not shown up as conversion when Parsed with php imap and sending back to sender

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, gmail, email, gmail-imap

hi I'm working with php imap functionality, 
I'm parsing mails from my mail box and storing them into mysql,:
i'm storing following information:

```
From
To
Subject
Content
Time of receiving mail
```

After one hour I'm sending back this mail. for sending mail i'm using ses mail of amazon.

I create a mail using the saved data and sending them to my gmail again.

But it is not showing up as group or conversion in gmail.

Here is my code for sending mail:

```
function sendEmail($pendingMail) {
    $sesAccUserName = 'noreply@mydomain.com';
    $ses = new AmazonSES(array("key" => AWSAccessKeyId, "secret" => AWSSecretKey));
    $source = trim($sesAccUserName);
    $destination = array('ToAddresses' => array(trim($pendingMail['email_reminder_send_to_address'])));
    $messageBody = $pendingMail['email_reminder_content'];
    $messageSubject = $pendingMail['email_reminder_subject'];
    $messageArr = array('Subject.Data' => 'Fwd: '.$messageSubject, 'Body.Html.Data' => $messageBody);
    $rSendEmail = $ses->send_email($source, $destination, $messageArr);
    if ($rSendEmail->status == 200) {
        changeStatus($pendingMail['email_reminder_id'], 'completed');
    } else {
        print_r($rSendEmail);
    }
}
```

Mail sent successfully but it is not grouped with the original message?
I think i googled a lot but not find anything useful..
I'm at beginner level about emails...
will you help me to solve this issue...
Thank you !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I research some gmail inbox mails and found that each mail have a `message-id` in header,

When we reply to mail the value of `message-id` is set to a header field `In Reply To:` of the reply mail (the mail we are sending in reply).

This message-id and In Reply To are responsible for grouping of message in gmail...